# Use f:attribute for commandButton instead of f:param for h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, button, parameters, hyperlink, command

I would like to include specific page depending upon button clicked.

As far `h:commandButton` used,I couldn't use `f:param`, so it looks like I should use `f:attribute` tag.

In case of `f:param` I would code like this:

```
<h:commandLink action="connectedFilein">
    <f:param name="fileId" value="#{fileRecord.fileId}"/>
<h:commandLink>

<c:if test="#{requestParameters.fileId!=null}">
    <ui:include src="fileOut.xhtml" id="searchOutResults"/>
</c:if>
```

What is the `f:attribuite` case?

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume that you're using JSF 1.x, otherwise this question didn't make sense. The `<f:param>` in `<h:commandButton>` is indeed not supported in legacy JSF 1.x, but it is supported since JSF 2.0.

The `<f:attribute>` can be used in combination with `actionListener`.

```
<h:commandButton action="connectedFilein" actionListener="#{bean.listener}">
    <f:attribute name="fileId" value="#{fileRecord.fileId}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
public void listener(ActionEvent event) {
    this.fileId = (Long) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fileId");
}
```

*(Assuming that it's of `Long` type, which is classic for an ID)*

---

Better is however to use the JSF 1.2 introduced `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

```
<h:commandButton action="connectedFilein">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.fileId}" value="#{fileRecord.fileId}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

---

Or when you're already running a Servlet 3.0/EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc) and your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0, then you could just pass it as method argument.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.show(fileRecord.fileId)}" />
```

with

```
public String show(Long fileId) {
    this.fileId = fileId;
    return "connectedFilein";
}
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, I'd strongly recommend to use JSF/Facelets tags instead of JSTL ones *whenever possible*.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.fileId != null}">
    <ui:include src="fileOut.xhtml" id="searchOutResults"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

*(A `<h:panelGroup>` is also possible and the best approach when using JSP instead of Facelets)*

Comment: any case I should use bean.property declaration this case? request parameters don't play here?I wanted make it simpler

Comment: JSF 2.0 supports `<f:param>` in `<h:commandButton>`. So if you can, upgrade it. Else your current best bet is `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

Comment: ok,I see,unfortunately we use JSF 1.2 in our project. thank you